# Terraform keeps spinning up instances after termination?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform

I wrote a terraform script to spin up an EC2 spot instance, and every time I terminate it, it automatically spins up a new instance. I don't understand this behavior. Why is this happening and how do I stop it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you requested your spot instance, you probably didn't specify the spot-type as 'one-time' so the request persists beyond instance termination.  Or in other words, when your instance is terminated the request begins anew and launches a new instance based on the same bid price, launch specification, etc.

From the [terraform documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/spot_instance_request.html#spot_type):

> spot_type - (Optional; Default: "persistent") If set to "one-time",
>   after the instance is terminated, the spot request will be closed.
>   Also, Terraform can't manage one-time spot requests, just launch them.

From the [AWS documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/spot-requests.html):

[image]

This will continue until you cancel the spot instance request. You can do this via the AWS Console, CLI ([cancel-spot-instance-requests](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/cancel-spot-instance-requests.html)), or via terraform by [destroying the resource](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/destroy.html).

### Further Reading

- [AWS Documentation - Cancelling a Spot Instance Request](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/spot-requests.html#using-spot-instances-cancel)